# Spring Boot can't load resources/js

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a simplistic Spring Boot project without security. Seems like Spring tries to map a JavaScript link to a controller request, this results in 500 and not loaded js files. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"static/js/..."` ?

Comment: doesnt work, neither /static/js/ytv.js nor ../static/js/ytv.js

Comment: @jarosik You need to use expression when you are using th: 
Try <script th:src="@{/js/index.js}"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the / before js. should be js/index.js

Comment: That how it works with security, I agree but it fails in my case

Answer (score 0):

Update the following way:

```
"../static/js/index.js"
```

../  represents one directory level higher

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need the `th:` prefix on the `src` attribute as there’s nothing in its value for Thymeleaf to process. Try the following instead:

```
<script src="/js/index.js"></script>
```